# How to use inline styling CSS with @media

Tags: css, overriding, media, bootstrap.min.css

Bootstrap.min.css is overriding everything I write in external CSS files. Inline seems to be the only thing that overrides Bootstrap. Does anyone know how I can use the following CSS script with inline scripting?

```
@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:80%}}
@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:80%}}
@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:80%}}
```

Comment: can't do media queries inline...

Comment: I've tried giving the ".container" div an id property but that didn't make any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*
Uncomment for option 1
@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:50% !important}}
@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:50% !important}}
@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:50% !important}}
*/
/*Option 2.. own style*/
@media (min-width:768px){.myclass{width:50% !important}}
@media (min-width:992px){.myclass{width:50% !important}}
@media (min-width:1200px){.myclass{width:50% !important}}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='container' style='background-color:red'>Hi Option 1</div>
<div class='container myclass' style='background-color:red'>Hi Option 2</div>
```

This should override Bootstrap styles (**!important**)

```
@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:80% !important}}
@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:80% !important}}
@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:80% !important}}
```

Comment: !important is not good practice... load your CSS after bootstrap.css and your css will over-write botstrap

Comment: I've tried that in the file as well but it had no effect.

Comment: It is currently loading after the bootstrap.css

Comment: While !important is not the best practice, I think it is best shot if you do not want to provide extra classes to your div